# Absolute positioning on animation failing on Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation, safari

I have a simple animation that put an element into "position: absolute" to translate it.
Works perfectly and as expected on Chrome.
On Safari, absolute positioning is completely ignored...

Fiddle : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvVZNv

Am I missing something ?

note: I don't want to `transform:translate` instead of `left`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `position` outside of the `keyframes`, [updated example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzjpzP) which works in Safari

Comment: Yeah Thanks but, I can't to do that in my real use case (more complex). But well, I'll accept your answer because the `position` css attribute appears to not be animatable : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties I just had luck it worked on Chrome.