# Safari keyframes position change doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, safari

I've faced the problem that safari doesn't change the position property in `@keyframes`.

Here is the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-keller-tb66vb?file=/src/styles.css

What I want to do here is to play animation on element with fixed position and at the very last frame make it absolutely positioned so that it appears on the green line in the middle of the page. In chrome, firefox, etc. it works as I expected, but in safari it stays fixed after animation finished. How can I force the element to be absolutely positioned after animation played?

Safari ver.13.0.3

Comment: The only thing I've came up with is that `position` [is not an animatable property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814807/absolute-positioning-on-animation-failing-on-safari#comment88640190_50814969) and due to that reason I've to add `position: absolute` css style via js after animation is finished